# How to get first objects of an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Observable which contains a list of users, and I want to take only a part of it, to handle pagination.
How can I do that? I've tried with filter but it doesn't workk :

```
this.users.filter(function (x: any, idx: number) {
  return idx < 3;
});
```

Comment: try using take operator... http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html

Comment: An observable doesn't really contain a value, it emits values. The question is IMHO unclear. Do you want a specific number of emitted events, or does your observable emit an array value and you want specific elements from this array.

Comment: I want specific elements from this array. Take will not work as I cannot specify startIndex, I don't necessarily want to take the x first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an array slice inside of a map operator. Depending on the page and page size you can set it up like so:

```js
const pageIndex = 0;
const pageSize = 3;
this.users.map((users: User[]) => {
    return users.slice(pageIndex, pageSize);
});
```